# Firefly 'Sky Hook' ship upgrade

Tags: firefly

There is a "Sky Hook" ship upgrade which "Counts as TRANSPORT" and "Requires Pilot to use". What exactly the rules of its use are? I see several possibilities:
1. It should be "equipped" by a Pilot going on a mission (like gear)
2. A Pilot should stay on the ship (because the ship is acting as a transport)
3. It always counts as a transport if you have a Pilot in the crew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the mission calls for a transport, they use the firefly as the transport. The transport is not expected to be in their pockets, so either they used the transport to get to the job, or they went back to the ship to do the job. You're good if you got a pilot on the job.

Comment: In other words, the rules make sense, so there's no reason to believe there's an exception here.

Comment: sorry, cannot get it yet, can the pilot equip some other gear or should he have his hands free to drive the firefly?

Comment: It's not gear, so yes he can. Having a gun in his pocket doesn't stop him from piloting.